# jquery ajax form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am getting `null` values from my text boxes.

The date is working perfectly but I can't get the data from the input boxes.

```
(function () {

    if ($('#contactform').length) {

        var $form = $('#contactform'),
            $loader = '<img src="images/preloader.gif" alt="Loading..." />';
        $form.append('<div class="hidden" id="contact_form_responce">');

        var $response = $('#contact_form_responce');
        $response.append('<p></p>');

        $form.submit(function (e) {

            $response.find('p').html($loader);

            var data = {
                action: "contact_form_request",
                values: $("#contactform").serialize()
            };

            //send data to server
            $.post("php/contact-send.php", data, function (response) {

                $(".wrong-data").removeClass("wrong-data");
                $response.find('img').remove();

                if (response.is_errors) {

                    $response.find('p').removeClass().addClass("error type-2");
                    $.each(response.info, function (input_name, input_label) {

                        $("[name=" + input_name + "]").addClass("wrong-data");
                        $response.find('p').append('Please enter correctly "' + input_label + '"!' + '</br>');
                    });

                } else {

                    $response.find('p').removeClass().addClass('success type-2');

                    if (response.info == 'success') {

                        $response.find('p').append('Your email has been sent!');
                        $form.find('input:not(input[type="submit"], button), textarea, select').val('').attr('checked', false);
                        $response.delay(1500).hide(400);
                    }

                    if (response.info == 'server_fail') {
                        $response.find('p').append('Server failed. Send later!');
                    }
                }

                // Scroll to bottom of the form to show respond message
                var bottomPosition = $form.offset().top + $form.outerHeight() - $(window).height();

                if ($(document).scrollTop() < bottomPosition) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: bottomPosition
                    });
                }

                if (!$('#contact_form_responce').css('display') == 'block') {
                    $response.show(450);
                }

            });

            e.preventDefault();

        });

    }

})();
```

And here is the php:

```
require_once "../includes/database.php";

$cname    = $_POST['name'];
$cemail   = $_POST['email'];
$cmessage = $_POST['message'];
$date     = date("Y-m-d");  
$sql      = "INSERT INTO messages (sendername,senderemail,message,datesent) VALUES (:name,:email,:message,:date)";
$qry      = $db->prepare($sql);

$qry->execute(array(
  ':name'    =>$cname,
  ':email'   =>$cemail,
  ':message' =>$cmessage,
  ':date'    =>$date
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way your assigning the POST data to your `$.post` function.

**Troublesome Code**

```
var data = {
   action: "contact_form_request",
   values: $("#contactform").serialize()
};
```

What's happening is the data is beind sent back as a multidimensional array and you need to include that on your php page.

Try changing `$_POST['name']` to `$_POST['values']['name']` to match the format of your jQuery. You'll need to make this change for each of your POST variables. You can always do `var_dump($_POST); die;` to ensure the nesting of the array.

I should mention, if you want to access your POST data directly (like in your original php) you should check out the [`jQuery .post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation.

The syntax to access your POST directly (`$_POST['name']`) would require the following code:

```
$.post('mypostpage.php', $('myform').serialize(), function(response) {
    //do work
});
```

Comment: thank you sir! it worked perfectly. i only dont get the success messages.

Comment: Looks like your php code should be responding with JSON. Response.info is what your looking for. Check out [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: exactly sir like this: response = $.parseJSON(response); after the $.post line but i removed it because i am getting errors.

Comment: You should open a new question with that issue, so we can keep this one on-topic. Post your output PHP code, and your jQuery. We need to see how your sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `e.preventDefault()` to the beginning of the function. Otherwise the form may be submitting without waiting to execute all the jQuery

Comment: i removed the e.preventDefault() and the whole page reloads after submitting.

Comment: No no. Move it to the beginning of the function

Comment: As long as `e.preventDefault()` is called before any `return` statements it doesn't matter where in the function it is. The entire code for the event handler function will be executed before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

post you're form html code

try wrapping your code with

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  });
```